# SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment) Crash when moving between VC Swift

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase, storekit

The IAP is working, but when I move between views and come back to the IAP VC, the app crashes in `SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().addPayment(payment)` `ERROR: EXC_BAD_ACCESS`

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I found the solution, you need to clean the `SKPaymentQueue` in the `viewWillDisappear`

> **Update Swift 4.x**

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
}
```

> **Swift 2.3**

```
override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated: animated)
    SKPaymentQueue.defaultQueue().removeTransactionObserver(self)
}
```

Comment: Been scratching my head for hours on this, great! Just wonder why would it crash if the queue is not cleared?

Comment: @sunfffd As it cannot start a new queue while there is one in the chain.

Comment: Thanks, I have a helper class to handle all IAP related task and now I have added two functions to add and remove the transaction observer. They are being called when a VC loads and disappear.

Comment: Thanks :) I was also having the same issue wondering why it sometimes crashes and sometimes not..

Comment: Can you help me understand why you use `viewWillDisappear` here and not `deinit`? Thanks. :)

Comment: @CliftonLabrum as this is a UIViewController, it might not deallocate, and therefore, you would want to make sure this gets cleared when the view disappears. Deinit will not get called if the view is in the stack, even if it is not currently presented.

Comment: Thank you. This was very helpful

Answer (score 0):

I use my class instead of viewController.

```
import StoreKit

open class IAPHelper: NSObject  {

     //Properties

     public init() {
         //init properties
         super.init()
         SKPaymentQueue.default().add(self)
     }

     deinit {
         SKPaymentQueue.default().remove(self)
     }
}
```